# Why is the class "active" on all of my navbar links?

Tags: php, nav, navigationbar

Here is my navbar.php file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Pointless?</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php
$active = "";
$pages = array("/index.php","/music/index.php","/pong/index.php");
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == $pages[0]) {
    $active .= "active";
}
else if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == $pages[1]) {
    $active .= "active";
}
else {
    $active = "";
}
echo "      <li class=\"$active\"><a href=\"/\">Home</a></li>\n      <li class=\"$active\"><a href=\"/music\">Music</a></li>\n      <li class=\"$active\"><a href=\"/pong\">Pong</a></li>";
?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Does anybody know why the attribute for ALL nav links is being filled in with "active"?
Because I put that addition to the variable in an if statement.

Also, is there anything I should change about the code/is unnecessary?

Comment: you are using same active variable to all that is why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting value of `$class` to active before creating the li. That's why its happening so.

you can update your code like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Pointless?</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<li class="<?php echo $url === '/test.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo $url === '/music/index.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="music">Music</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo $url === '/pong/index.php' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="pong">Pong</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```